# Updating object on Python < arcade library >

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, methods

I'm currently coding in some assignment.
I create a class named Ship and created some methods to make the object class ship be able to move.

```
class Ship():
def __init__(self):
    self.center.x = 400
    self.center.y = 300
    self.velocity.dx = .25
    self.velocity.dy = .25

def advance_down(self):

    self.center.y = self.center.y - self.velocity.dy
```

This is my code

```
def check_keys(self):
"""
    This function checks for keys that are being held down.
    You will need to put your own method calls in here.
    """
        if arcade.key.DOWN in self.held_keys:
            self.ship1.advance_down()
```

advance down just changes the position

```
    def on_key_press(self, key: int, modifiers: int):
    """
    Puts the current key in the set of keys that are being held.
    You will need to add things here to handle firing the bullet.
    """
            if key == arcade.key.DOWN:
               self.held_keys.add(key)
```

This adds the current key being pressed to the set of self.held_keys.
I'm calling an update of the positon.

```
 def update(self, delta_time):
    """
    Update each object in the game.
    :param delta_time: tells us how much time has actually elapsed
    ""

    self.ship1.advance_down()
```

when I run the code I'm able to display everything just fine but it's not doing anything once I press my keys.
Any ideas why?